# Big floor symbols

Tags: symbols

When I write

```
\lfloor\dfrac{1}{2}\rfloor
```

the floors come out too short to cover the fraction. How can I lengthen the floor symbols?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You could use `\left...\right` for stretchable delimiters, or perhaps one of the pairs of the `\bigl...\bigr` family of commands:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\Bigl\lfloor\dfrac{1}{2}\Bigr\rfloor\qquad
\left\lfloor\dfrac{1}{2}\right\rfloor
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

A LaTeX-y way to handle this issue would be to define a macro called, say, `\floor`, using the `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` device of the `mathtools` package. With such a setup, you can pass an optional explicit sizing instruction -- `\Big` and `\bigg` in the example code below -- or you can use the "starred" version of the macro -- `\floor*` -- to autosize the left and right hand brackets. Both possibilities are pursued in the following code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for "\DeclarePairedDelimiter" macro
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\floor}{\lfloor}{\rfloor}
\begin{document}
\[
\floor[\Big]{\frac{1}{2}}
\qquad
\floor[\bigg]{\frac{1}{2}}
\qquad
\floor*{\frac{1}{2}}  % autosize vertical dim. of brackets
\]
\end{document}
```